# Выпадающий список и вывод информации из MySQL

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Как правильно составить запрос, в котором при нажатии на выпадающий список выводились данные из БД?

```
<?php
echo '<form method="post">';
echo '<select name="table" size="1" >';
echo '<option selected="selected" value="second">Таблица</option>';
echo '<option value="zerno"> Зерно </option>';
echo '<option value="kykyr"> Кукуруза </option>'; 
echo '<option value="furniture"> Мягкая мебель </option>'; 
echo '<option value="children"> Детские </option>'; 
echo '<option value="bedrooms"> Спальни </option>'; 
echo '<option value="antechambers"> Прихожие </option>'; 
echo '<option value="tables"> Компьютерные столы </option>'; 
echo '<option value="cabinets"> Шкафы </option>'; 
echo '<option value="interior"> Интерьер </option>';
echo '</select>';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Выбрать" />';
 echo '</form>';

if ($_POST['table']=='zerno') $table=$_POST['table'];
if ($_POST['table']=='kykyr') $table=$_POST['table'];
if ($_POST['table']=='furniture') $table=$_POST['table'];
if ($_POST['table']=='children') $table=$_POST['table'];
if ($_POST['table']=='bedrooms') $table=$_POST['table'];
if ($_POST['table']=='antechambers') $table=$_POST['table'];
if ($_POST['table']=='tables') $table=$_POST['table'];
if ($_POST['table']=='cabinets') $table=$_POST['table'];

$stable=$_POST['table']; 
if(isset($stable)) 
{ 
   $qr_result1 = mysql_query("select * from tb_dom" . $table . " WHERE `user_dom`='$user'")
   or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то типа такого можно попробовать:

```
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($qr_result)){
    echo '<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="uft-8">';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td><select id="namevpn" name="uname">
    <option value="'. $data['name'] .'">'. $data['name'] .'</option>
    </select></td>';
```

Ну и почитать про работу с БД

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895035/populate-a-select-box-with-php-mysql - тут подобная проблема решается

В вашем примере как-то так получиться

```
$stable=$_POST['table']; 
if(isset($stable)) { 
    $qr_result1 = mysql_query("select * from tb_dom" . $table . " WHERE user_dom='$user'") or die(mysql_error()); 
} 
echo '<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="uft-8">';

while($data = mysql_fetch_array($qr_result1)){   
    echo '<tr>'; 
    echo '<td><select id="uname" name="uname"> <option value="'. $data['name'] .'">'. $data['name'] .'</option> </select></td>';
 } 
?>
```

Comment: извините я новичок в программировании. код должен выглядеть так? 
     $stable=$_POST['table']; 
      if(isset($stable)) 
      { 
       $qr_result1 = mysql_query("select * from tb_dom" . $table . "        WHERE `user_dom`='$user'")
      or die(mysql_error());
       } 
       while($data = mysql_fetch_array($qr_result1)){
         echo '<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="uft-8">';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td><select id="namevpn" name="uname">
    <option value="'. $data['name'] .'">'. $data['name'] .'</option>
    </select></td>';
}

?>

Comment: В ответе поправил, прошу прощения пишу наколенке не проверял... суть. что в цикл while нужно поставить только селекты, а начало и конец формы нвынести за его пределы.

Comment: переделал код но теперь при выводе выдает Table 'mrakr226_wond.tb_dommyaso' doesn't exist  в базе все таблицы есть. Почему tb_dommyaso выводит слитно если должно tb_dom.myaso Это я туплю или ошибка еще где то ?

Comment: надо смотреть, где в коде ошибка ..может не сколько раз переменную определили... внимательней гянуть на все ..

Comment: изменил строку  $qr_result1 = mysql_query("select * from tb_dom  WHERE user_dom='$user'") or die(mysql_error());     вместо результата из ячейки появился маленький выпадающий список пустой. что то я вообще в дебри залез. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Кстати, посмотрите, у вас в вопросе  ошибку вижу ... 
$stable=$_POST['table'];  а дальше вы пишите $table  - посмотрите наверняка есть еще ошибки и переменные в запрос как по мне надо через точки вставлять ... рекомендую прочитать быстренько и полненько про переменные и подключение к ДБ... просто у вас вопросов много ,а вводных данных мало и врятли кроме вас - кто-то захочет ильно углубляться)

Comment: спасибо за помощь! Не думал что будет такие заморочки с простым выводом данных при выборе из выпадающего списка. Буду дальше разбирать